# Непонятная ошибка Unity кидает ошибку на скрипт который я даже не трогал

Tags: unity3d

Делаю 3Д Игру FPS. Всё работало, и тут Unity кидает ошибку на код
который я даже не трогал.

```
ArgumentException: Input Button Submit is not setup.
 To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInput.GetButtonDown (System.String buttonName) (at D:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/BaseInput.cs:126)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ShouldActivateModule () (at D:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:236)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () (at D:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:350)
```

Comment: А можно хоть на код взглянуть. Сегодня маги отдыхают

Answer (score 1):

> Вы не приложили ни малейшей дополнительной информации, кроме текста ошибки, и все же я, героическая мать Тереза, смог по крупицам собрать информацию и, проведя тщательнейшее исследование, найти определенное...

**Короче**, считаем ссылки: [раз](https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1801519.html), [два](https://forum.unity.com/threads/argumentexception-input-button-fire1-is-not-setup.336458/), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401050/when-using-unity-engine-i-get-the-error-argumentexception-input-button-w-is-not).

---

Скорее всего в вашем коде есть подобная строка:

```
Input.GetButtonDown("Submit");
```

Так вот, если вы пройдете по пути (который, между прочим, указан в тексте ошибки): `Edit -> Project Settings -> Input`, то обнаружите там список всех осей *Axes* и кнопок *Button*. Есть, например, оси "Vertical", "Horizontal", кнопки "Fire1"...

Так вот вы пытаетесь получить кнопку `Submit`, однако в этом списке ее скорее всего нет. Вам следует проверить ее наличие и (важно!) капитализацию: регистр букв важен!

Comment: Есть такая мода у новичков программирования: видишь ошибку - не читая начинай паниковать и просить помощи.... Я и сам когда-то таким страдал :D